# Has space weather ever impacted spacecraft launch schedules?

Tags: launch, planning, space-weather

Has [space weather](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_weather) ever affected spacecraft launches, and do launch providers check it before spacecraft go to space?

I know there is [space turbulence](https://www.nsf.gov/discoveries/disc_summ.jsp?cntn_id=127634) and it can influence a spacecraft underway, but can space weather affect the launch schedule itself?

Comment: Not only launches, but also early termination of flight in the event of powerful flares on the Sun.

Comment: I guess that something like a period with a strong solar storm would seem to be a poor choice for a launch window since it affects if not the craft, at least the ability to track/communicate with the craft.

Comment: Also, I found out how space weather can be forecasted: Theoretical/computer modeling (eg of the Sun's 11 year sunspot cycle) Ground-based observations. Satellite based observations

Comment: @A.Rumlin I've added a bounty

Comment: It [nearly triggered a nuclear war in 1967](https://www.businessinsider.com.au/cold-war-geomagnetic-storm-radio-disruption-2016-8).

Comment: @Fred I hate it when that happens

Comment: @uhoh: I'm glad there were ***some*** sensible people back then & a crisis was averted.

Comment: @uhoh This is not an answer, but a recitation of memories: " In the 70-80s ...There was even a case when a spacecraft was immediately de-orbited due to the data received [about the activity of the Sun]." 
Most likely, the text refers to a photographic reconnaissance satellite. I could not find such information about manned spacecraft.
https://ussuriysk.bezformata.com/listnews/kosmos-sluzhba-solntca-stoit/45771067/

Answer (score 5):

In [2014 a solar flare delayed the launch](https://www.nbcnews.com/science/space/huge-solar-flare-delays-private-rocket-launch-space-station-n5926) of a private cargo delivery to the International Space Station by 24 hours due to concerns over space radiation.

> The event occurred as the commercial spaceflight company Orbital Sciences Corp. was preparing to launch a landmark cargo delivery flight to the space station with its Antares rocket and robotic Cygnus spacecraft.

The huge solar flare was rated as "an X1.2-class sun storm — the strongest class of solar flares the sun experience".